# Looking for best way (Ajax, HTML checkbox question)

Tags: php, ajax

I'm working on a project. suppose If Admin click on approved checkbox, then account is activated using ajax. and if admin click on banned checkbox, then user deactivated from database.
I don't know what is the best way to do this. Any advice thanks you so much.

This is checkbox for approved.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="q" value="<?php echo $userid;?>" onchange="User(this.value)"/>
<input type="hidden" name="doAction" id="doAction" value="Approved" />
```

This is checkbox for approved.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="q" value="<?php echo $userid;?>" onchange="User(this.value)"/>
<input type="hidden" name="doAction2" id="doAction2" value="Banned" />
```

And this is my ajax short code

```
if('Approved' == doAction) 
{

    xmlhttp.open("GET","adminPanel.php?q="+str+"&doAction="+doAction,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
else if ('Banned' == doAction2) 
{


    xmlhttp.open("GET","adminPanel.php?q="+str+"&doAction="+doAction2,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: This looks fine to me.  Is it not working?

Comment: both checkbox display same output. In adminPanel.php I'm just displaying the variable. for example `echo $_GET['doAction']; and echo $_GET['q'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is a reasonable way to do it. Though you shouldn't output the userid value in the form and rely on that to authorize the user. Because you cannot trust that the "q" parameter specifies the correct user. Instead you should check what userid the users session cookie corresponds to. If that userid is just a normal user and not the admin, that user can obviously not ban other users. Then, as always, validate the doAction parameter in adminPanel.php or else you'll open yourself up to SQL injection attacks.

Also check out jQuery which makes it much easier to do AJAX calls.

Comment: Lindqvist - Thanks for suggestion. Normal user cannot access  `adminPanel.php`  file. This is only for Admin.

Comment: But nothing prevents someone from forging that request WITHOUT going through adminPanel.php. Consider the case of a a disgruntled former admin - they could possibly know the URL of your ajax handler and send off whatever requests they want, completely bypassing any verification in your adminPanel.php - always have server-side validation.

Answer (score 0):

Now my Code working. here is my changes.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="q" value="<?php echo $userid;?>"  onchange="approveUser(this.value,doAction.value)" />
<input type="hidden" name="doAction" id="doAction" value="Approved" />

<input type="checkbox" id="q" value="<?php echo $userid;?>"  onchange="approveUser(this.value,doAction.value)" />
<input type="hidden" name="doAction" id="doAction" value="Approved" />
```

I passed one more parameter to ajax function. Now its working

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","adminPanel.php?q="+str+"&doAction="+action,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```